# Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

What's the correct way to pass a bundle to the activity that is being launched from the current one? Shared properties?

Answer (score 467, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

Then, in the launched Activity, you would read them via:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the Bundle from the Intent:

```
Bundle extras = myIntent.getExtras();
extras.put*(info);
```

Or an entire bundle:

```
myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: And from the resulting intent you call getIntent().getExtras().get*() to get what's been stored before.

Answer (score 17):

**Passing data from one Activity to Activity in android**

An intent contains the action and optionally additional data. The data can be passed to other activity using intent `putExtra()` method. Data is passed as extras and are `key/value pairs`. The key is always a String. As value you can use the primitive data types int, float, chars, etc. We can also pass **`Parceable and Serializable`** objects from one activity to other.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, <your value here>);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Retrieving bundle data from android activity**

You can retrieve the information using  **`getData()`** methods on the Intent object. The **Intent** object can be retrieved via the **`getIntent()`** method.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (null != intent) { //Null Checking
    String StrData= intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
    int NoOfData = intent.getIntExtra(KEY, defaultValue);
    boolean booleanData = intent.getBooleanExtra(KEY, defaultValue);
    char charData = intent.getCharExtra(KEY, defaultValue); 
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass values from one activity to another activity using the Bundle. In your current activity, create a bundle and set the bundle for the particular value and pass that bundle to the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key,value);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your NewActivity, you can get this bundle and retrive your value.

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String value = bundle.getString(key);
```

You can also pass data through the intent. In your current activity, set intent like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key,value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your NewActivity, you can get that value from intent like this,

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
```

Comment: Why using a bundle while the intent object has the getExtra and putExtra methods ?

Answer (score 3):

**Write this is the activity you are in:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("string_name","string_to_pass");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the NextActivity.java

```
Intent getIntent = getIntent();
//call a TextView object to set the string to
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
text.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("string_name"));
```

This works for me, you can try it.

Source:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-the-data-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android-application/