# How send return value through Intent in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that opens another class using intent :

```
private void createRepository(){
        Intent j = new Intent(this, Repository.class);
        startActivityForResult(j, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

In Repository.class we have the **onActivityResult** method :

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
              //String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
              num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));

            }    

          }    
        break;
      }
      finish();
    }
```

I don't know how I can return the value of **num** to the first class (that creates Repository.class).
Thank you for your help.
Michaël

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you got the directions mixed up.

In the Repository class you have to `setResult()` before calling finish. For additional Data you can `putExtra()` data.

For example, set your result in the `onCreate()` function.

In your calling class (the one that starts Repository) you overwrite `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` and get data with `data.getBundleExtra()`.

Androids reference for Intent and Activity has good descriptions and the samples also contain a ReceiveResult and SendResult sample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I used this post to resolve my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity