# How to send an array using Bundle?

Tags: android, arrays, bundle

In my app I have an `array`

```
List<Friends> friends =new ArrayList<Friends>();
```

where **Friends** is :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Friends implements Serializable{

private final String name;
private final String id;

public Friends(String name, String id){
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
    }
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getId()
{
    return id;
}

}
```

I want to send this `array` to an other `Activity` and I don't know how should I do.

I tried to send them one by one but it not worked. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayList is Serializable, so `Bundle.putSerializable("myList", friendList);` should be working.

I would advice however to make your Friend class Parcelable, then use [Bundle.putParcelableArrayList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29)

Note that to pass data to another activity, you should use intent extras. See [Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)