# How to pass Facebook Session Information Between two Activities

Tags: android, session

I would like to pass Facebook session information between two acvtivities so that I can authenticate one user in 1st session and use that session information to post a message to a wall in 2nd activity.

What's the way of doing this simple task? Should I keep token and expire information and create a new session with these two variables or some other way?

I'm struggling on that one for one week already so prompt answers, sample code, info etc appreciated very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Answer (score 0):

From the 1st activity, you should start the 2nd activity by calling `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, passing the Facebook session to the sending `Intent`.

```
intent.putExtra("FBSession", sessionValue); // assuming session in a string
```

In 2nd activity, inside `onCreate()`, calling `getIntent().getString("FBSession")` to receive value sent from 1st activity.

Comment: By using intends I think you can only pass primitive data types like int, string etc. right?

Comment: By custom objects, you can try serialize them but it would result in slow performance. Or you can implement `Parcelable`. Please refer to my tutorial on `Parcelable Object`: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/pass-complex-object-structure-to-intent/