# How to pass data from a selected item in a listview to another activity?

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code. I have the data in the object `o`. There are three set of values in `o` (description, name, image url). I need these data to be initialized to a string and pass it to other activity using intent. How do I get each value in the object. Each list item has a image, item name and item description.

```
fp_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pos"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Object o = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(FeaturedProductsActivity.this, ShowProduct.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use bundle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Answer (score 3):

Better thing is to make you Custom Object `Parcelable`

the Other option is to pass these values one by one as:

```
Intent i=new Intent(FeaturedProductsActivity.this,ShowProduct.class);
i.putString("desc", o.getDescription());
i.putString("name", o.getName());
// rest of your values
```

ang get these values in `ShowProduct` Activity as:

```
Intent in = this.getIntent();
String name = in.getStringExtra("name");
String desc = in.getStringExtra("desc");
//rest of you values
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass object from One activity to another using Intent. Yo have to use Parcelable interface . see this.

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Answer (score 2):

```
      Bundle bundle =new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("memId",o.getId() );
                Intent newIntent=new Intent(friendsOffrinends.this,RestaurantDetails.class);
                newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way :

1-make a class which extend Application.
2-make an object of what you want to transfer.
3-make its set and get.
4-in onitemclick set the value.
5-get the value wherever you want.

Example:

1-make a class which extend Application.
2-make an object of what you want to transfer.
3-make its set and get.

```
public class App extends Application {
private static yourObject  obj;

public yourObject getobj() {
return obj;
}
public void setobj(yourObject obj) {
this.obj= obj;
}
}
```

in your class

```
fp_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    yourObject  o =(yourObject) parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
   App.setobj(o);
}
```

}

in any other where all over the application classes

```
//here you will get your object which you have set on item click
yourObject obj=App.getobj;
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have data you can use Bundle or you can directly attach data with Intent e.g. `in.putExtra(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("description", o.get(position).getdescription())
startActivity(descriptionIntent);
```

And in the second activity:

```
Intent descriptionIntent = getIntent();
String description = descriptionIntent.getExtras().getString("description");
```