# How to add the same View from Activity (A) to an other Activity (B)

Tags: android, view, android-activity, checkbox, addition

Im a beginner in Android and I have the following Problem:

I've created a TabHost within two tabs: activity A and activity B.

Activity A consists of a linear Layout with dynamically added checkboxes:

```
Activity A:

1[ ] 
2[ ] 
3[x] 
4[ ] 
5[x]
```

Activity B consists of an empty linear Layout.

Now I want the checked checkboxes from activity A to be added in activity B:

```
Activity B:

3[x]
5[x]
```

These checkboxes should disappear if they were unchecked...

```
Activity B:

...is empty again.
```

What technique should be used to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass information from one ACtivity to another is usually by passing a bundle (sounds like it fits your case).  You can pass the strings or numbers of the selected boxes from A to be ([here is an explanation of passing bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)) then in be add those check boxes according to the bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I think this could be the solution for my Problem. Can you give me a short example in code? Now I know how to get Strings or Ints but how can I get the checkbox View from this data?

Comment: It is not very practical to pass a whole view.  I don't know your demands but I would say pass the views titles to the next activity and then rebuild the check boxes based on number of titles