# How to get results in new activity from the previous activity results in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities say X and y. In x there is edittext n 6 radiobutton if user clicks button the value gets retrieved from database based on input from edittext n radiobutton. the values should be displayed in next activity y. can yu pls help in giving snippet..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily pass data from one activity to another using Bundle or Intent.

Lets look at the following example using Bundle:

```
//creating an intent to call the next activity
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.NextActivity");
Bundle b = new Bundle();

//This is where we put the data, you can basically pass any 
//type of data, whether its string, int, array, object
//In this example we put a string
//The param would be a Key and Value, Key would be "Name"
//value would be "John"
b.putString("Name", "John");

//we put the bundle to the Intent
i.putExtra(b);

startActivity(i, 0);
```

In "NextActivity" you can retrieve the data using the following code:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra();
//you retrieve the data using the Key, which is "Name" in our case
String data = b.getString("Name");
```

How about using only Intent to transfer data. Lets look at the example

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.NextActivity");
int highestScore = 405;
i.putExtra("score", highestScore);
```

In "NextActivity" you can retrieve the data:

```
int highestScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("score");
```

Now you would ask me, whats the difference between Intent and Bundle, they seems like
they do exactly the same thing.

The answer is yes, they both do exactly the same thing. But if you want to transfer alot of data, variables, large array you would need to use Bundle, as they have more methods for transferring large amount of data.(i.e.  If your only passing one or two variable then just go with Intent.

Comment: i have the values retrieved in cursor variable then how to pass??

Answer (score 0):

You should put the values into a bundle and pass that bundle to the intent that's starting the next activity.  Sample code is in the answer to this question:  [Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

Comment: i have cursor values retrieved from db. how to pass that??

Comment: Generally not a good idea, as your cursor isn't the data it's a handle on the open socket.  Instead, consider passing either the query url or else parse the cursor into a serializeable object in the first activity and pass that object on.

Comment: can we directly pass db.query from one intent to another intent and display results in second?? if so how ?

Comment: I don't believe so, b/c the cursor isn't serializeable afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data that you would like to send with the Intent you are calling to go to the next activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNextClass.class);
i.putExtra("yourKey", "yourKeyValue");
startActivity(i);
```

In YourNextClass activity, you can get the passed data by using

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
    String data = extras.getString("yourKey");
    }
```