# How to mark a call URGENT in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I'm creating an application in which I'm trying to override the default android dial to include one more button "URGENT". 
The idea is that if the application is installed on 2 phones, and one phone mark the call as "URGENT", the other phone's receiver screen (which will also be overridden) will turn "RED" to show the receiver that the call is "URGENT".

**I'm using below code to call but not sure how to include "URGENT" parameter along with it.**

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:03000000000"));

        startActivity(intent);`

Please suggest if there is any way to achieve this functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Read about passing a bundle to intent here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Answer (score 0):

You can't just make up parameters to an intent-  the intent your calling has to support that field.  And I'm not sure the phone network has an idea of an "urgent" call at all.  I know I wouldn't want it to-  every telemarketer in the world would use it for every call.  But if you really want to go through with this, you'd need an out of band way to send data to that other phone, and you'd need to get it there before the call goes through.  You could try having it tell a server you own that a call is going to be urgent, and pushing that via GCM to the receiver, but timing would be hard to get.