# Taking value from another class from adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I need help here. I'm trying to take a value from my class and take it to another class to be processed.... My problem is, the value is from an adapter. I'm stuck here.

Here is my code :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(arg2).toString(),3000).show();
     Intent newI = new Intent (this, PDetail.class); 
     startActivity (newI);
 }});
```

This is the class i want to call (PDetail.class) :

```
public class PDetail extends Activity {
 //Create ct;
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(arg2).toString(),3000).show();
}
```

My question is, how can i get the "data" value from the first class??? Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/819427/513413

Comment: Thanks for the references

Comment: I think his problem is actually getting it from the adapter. Usually adapters have the method `getItem` which will return the object associated with that position

Comment: Well, actually thats what i mean....@SmartLemon

Comment: @SmartLemon sometimes not always. sometimes (if you are using holder pattern) for better performance you need to return null instead. Look at here for more info: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: In the context of an ArrayAdapter it will return an object with the type it was created with, or object. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int)

Comment: Returning null would suggest the method has been overridden, just not implemented

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
     Intent newI = new Intent (this, PDetail.class); 
     newI.putExtra("value",data.get(arg2));
     startActivity (newI);
 }});
```

In your second activity

```
   String value =getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: That's exactly what i did but it won't work...... the error says that i have to erase the argument .... it became like this :                  **Intent newI = new Intent ();** Any Idea ??? why i cant put  **Intent newI = new Intent (this, PDetail.class);**

Comment: You should use classaName  Intent newI = new Intent (firstclassName.this, PDetail.class);

Comment: It shows no error.... but still it forced close when i run it.... anyway thx for your reply