# Reload same activity but pass bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, reload

I am trying to reload my activity and pass a `bundle`, but I'm getting an empty (null) bundle.

Reload activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
MyActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

`onCreate` activity and I should get the `bundle`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
   if (savedInstance != null)
   {
   }
   else
   {
      Log.i("d", "IS NULL !");
   }
}
```

I'm getting null.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `OnCreate()` you should do like this :

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.i("Value", extras.getString("key"));
}
```

Instead of this

```
if (savedInstance != null){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First start the activity and then call `finish()` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

Then receive the bundle extras like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Finally, you can put conditions to check if it's correct like:

```
if(bundle != null)
{
}
else
{
   Log.i("d", "IS NULL !");
}
```