# Why is Bundle data giving an error while retrieving?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have written a very small code to pass data via bundle between two activities. Now I guess I have followed the proper steps, but the code is giving error. Forgive me if it is a very stupid mistake but I am stuck and I am blind on this code, Please help me. Here is the code..

```
package veniteck.solutions.mapmymetro;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
    ImageView findnearestsource, findnearestdestination, getroute;
    String[] stops = {
            "Bangalore International Exhibition Center", "Jindal", "Manjunathnagar", "Nagasandra", "Dasarahalli", "Jalahalli", "Peenya Industry", "Peenya", "Yeswanthpur Industry", "Yeswanthpur", "Sandal Soap Factory", "Mahalaxmi", "Rajajinagar", "Kuvempu Road", "Srirampura", "Sampige Road", "Kempegowda Interchange", "Chikpet", "K R Market", "National College", "Lalbagh", "South End Circle", "Jayanagar", "R V Road Interchange", "Banashankari", "J P Nagar", "Puttenahalli", "Anjanapura Cross Road", "Krishna Leela Park", "Vajrahalli", "Thaighattapura", "Anjanapura/NICE Junction", "Kengeri", "R V College of Engineering", "Bangalore University Cross", "Rajarajeshwari Nagar", "Nayandahalli", "Mysore Road", "Deepanjali Nagar", "Attiguppe", "Vijayanagar", "Hosahall1i", "Magadi Road", "Sir M Vishweshwariah", "Vidhana Soudha", "M G Road Interchange", "Trinity", "Halasuru", "Indiranagar", "S V Road", "Baiyyappanahalli", "Jyotipura", "K R Puram", "Mahadevpura", "Garudacharpalya", "Doddanekkundi Induatrial State", "Vishweshwariah Industrial State", "Kundanahalli", "Vydhehi Hospital", "Satya Sai Medical Institute", "ITPB", "Kadugodi Industrial Area", "Ujjwal Vidhyalaya", "Whitefield", "Nagawara", "Arabic College", "Venkateshpura", "Tannery Town", "Pottery Town", "Cantonment Railway Station", "Shivajinagar", "Vellara Junction", "Langford Town", "Mico Bosch", "Dairy Circle", "Swagath Road Cross", "Jayadeva Hospital Interchange", "J P Nagar 4th Phase", "IIMB", "Hulimavu", "Gottigere", "Ragigudda Temple", "BTM Layout", "Silk Board", "HSR Layout", "Oxford College", "Muneshwara Nagar", "Chikkabegur", "Basapura Road", "Hosa Road", "Electronics City 1", "Electronics City 2", "Huskur Road", "Hebbagodi", "Bommasandra"
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AutoCompleteTextView source = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autofillsource);
        source.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_details, stops));

        AutoCompleteTextView destination = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autofilldestination);
        destination.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_details, stops));

        findnearestsource = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.findnearestsource);
        findnearestsource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        findnearestdestination = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.findnearestdestination);
        findnearestdestination.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        getroute = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.getroute);
        getroute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Route.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }   
        });



         // SECTION FOR BUNDLE CODE

        String src = source.getText().toString();
        String dest = destination.getText().toString();


         Bundle b = new Bundle();

         b.putString("srcstop", src);
         b.putString("deststop", dest);

         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Route.class);
         in.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(in);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

The Other Activity

**Route.java**

```
    public class Route  extends Activity 
    {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.routemap);



         // SECTION FOR BUNDLE CODE



          TextView RouteText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RouteText);

          Intent in = getIntent();

          //Getting bundle
          Bundle b = in.getExtras();

          //Getting data from bundle
          String Source = b.getString("srcstop");
          String Destination = b.getString("deststop");

          //Binding values to TextViews
           RouteText.setText("Getting route directions from " +Source +"to " +Destination);


    }
    }
```

Here is Logcat output..

[image: Logcat]

**Logcat In Text Format**

```
10-04 12:38:13.722: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 8173K/8455K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
10-04 12:38:13.732: I/dalvikvm-heap(972): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.881MB for 896016-byte allocation
10-04 12:38:13.852: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9048K/9351K, paused 74ms+14ms, total 120ms
10-04 12:38:13.922: I/Choreographer(972): Skipped 144 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-04 12:38:14.032: D/gralloc_goldfish(972): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-04 12:38:14.381: I/Choreographer(972): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-04 12:38:26.531: I/Choreographer(972): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-04 12:38:37.222: D/AndroidRuntime(972): Shutting down VM
10-04 12:38:37.222: W/dalvikvm(972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{veniteck.solutions.mapmymetro/veniteck.solutions.mapmymetro.Route}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at veniteck.solutions.mapmymetro.Route.onCreate(Route.java:25)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-04 12:38:37.242: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  ... 11 more
```

**When I dont enter anything in the textviews on 1st activity** 
[image]

**I am able to go to Route.java.**

[image]

**But when I enter something,**
[image]

**and click get route, it crashes.** 
[image]

Really really sorry if this ques is stupid enough not to be on SO. But I am really not getting the solution.

Comment: can you post the stack trace here. your snap shot is not clear. whihc is line not 25 `Route.java`?

Comment: String Source = b.getString("srcstop");


 String Destination = b.getString("deststop");

Comment: You bundle is null, please check here the accepted answer to see how to correctly set it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Comment: move this inside imageview click `String src = source.getText().toString();
        String dest = destination.getText().toString();`. Also move these `Bundle b = new Bundle()

         b.putString("srcstop", src);
         b.putString("deststop", dest)` and `startActivtiy` to imageview click. your values you put in bundle is null

Comment: this shld be inside ur on click


        String src = source.getText().toString();
        String dest = destination.getText().toString();


         Bundle b = new Bundle();

         b.putString("srcstop", src);
         b.putString("deststop", dest);

         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Route.class);
         in.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(in);

Comment: just change the getApplicationContext to activity.this ,if not works then try to send data through intent.putextra. it should works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move these inside  `onClick`. Change to

```
getroute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          String src = source.getText().toString();
          String dest = destination.getText().toString();
          Bundle b = new Bundle();
          b.putString("srcstop", src);
          b.putString("deststop", dest);
          Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Route.class);
          in.putExtras(b);
          startActivity(in);

        }   
    });
```

The below is outside click listener. So the strings are null. Move it inside `onClick`

```
String src = source.getText().toString();
String dest = destination.getText().toString();
```

Also make these changes

```
final AutoCompleteTextView source = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autofillsource);
final AutoCompleteTextView destination = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autofilldestination);
```

Comment: Accepted. Thanx a lott.. I knew something small and stupid was happening. Wasnt able to track. Really thanx a tonn..

Answer (score 1):

try writing the following code in the onclick() of mainActivity:

```
        String src = source.getText().toString();
        String dest = destination.getText().toString();


         Bundle b = new Bundle();

         b.putString("srcstop", src);
         b.putString("deststop", dest);

         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Route.class);
         in.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

yourcode is outside click listener.. Make it inside click listener and it should work..

```
String src = source.getText().toString();
String dest = destination.getText().toString();
```