# How to pass Multiple information from one screen to another screen in android

Tags: android

I have a sign-up form, and I have to pass all info filled in that form to another screen. I know how to display if there is one field, but in sign-up form there are multiple fields. so I want to know how to display all the info.

Comment: Is the signup form an activity or  a fragment?

Answer (score 3):

If you are launching a new activity, just create a `Bundle`, add your values, and pass it into the new activity by attaching it to the `Intent` you are using:

```
/*
 * In your first Activity:
 */

String value = "something you want to pass along";
String anotherValue = "another something you would like to pass along";

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value", value);
bundle.putString("another value", anotherValue);

// create your intent

intent.putExtra(bundle);
startActivity(intent);


/*
 * Then in your second activity:
 */

Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String value = bundle.getString("value");
String anotherValue = bundle.getString("another value");
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass User data(multiple info) from  one screen to another screen :

1. Create a model for user with setter and getter method.
2. make this class Serializable or Parcelable (Prefer) .
3. Create object of user class and set all data using setter method.
4. Pass this object from one activity to another by using putSerializable.

   `Person mPerson = new Person();`

   ```
   mPerson.setAge(25);  
   Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
   Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();  
   mBundle.putSerializable(SER_KEY,mPerson);  
   mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);  

   startActivity(mIntent);
   ```
5. And get this object from activity 2 in on create methode.

   Person mPerson = (Person)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(SER_KEY);

and SER_KEY will be same.

for more detail please go to this link:

http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing.html

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bundle for passing values from one screen to other

[Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)