# Activity not starting when using putExtra()

Tags: android, marker

I am clicking marker and i am trying to open new activity. I can open activity when i dont `putExtra` information in intent but when i try to sent to 2nd activity 10 strings it shows me this:

```
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251): Exception in new application when starting activity com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample/.Builder
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:793)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1157)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:526)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6192)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6254)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2407)
07-12 19:40:04.508: W/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251): Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{b21e6f4 4200:com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample/u0a57}
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:793)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1157)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:526)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6192)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6254)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2407)
07-12 19:40:04.508: A/ActivityManager(1251):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I don't even know where to start to read this because i do not know what is going on. I havent go this error in my life. Could it be something like a timeout and i cannot put extra information in intent so much or is it something else. Because i tried to send in one string a lot of information and it worked. But when i put so much extra info it just crashes.

Comment: If you read through it you'll notice a part of the error on the 2nd line from top that says `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`   Reduce the amount of data your are sending via the Extra.. :)

Comment: This should be an answer, instead of a comment. It is the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah agree with GreyBeardedGeek if you send your comment as answer @scarag i will accept and thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your are sending to much data. Try sending as a array or as Bundle
check this answer:[BUNDLE DATA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819427/4487949)

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says you are sending to large data in the bundle. Try sending it as an object and use putSerialisable