# Passing data from second activity to first activity

Tags: android

I am trying to pass Bundle from second activity to the first(launch) activity. In order not to get NPE on launch, I am checking if bundle != null, however, it looks, like even after returning from second activity with Bundle, it still doesn't run the "if" body. 
Here is my part of code of first activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null) {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setStatus(bundle.getInt("Status"));
            player.setName(bundle.getString("Name"));
            addPlayerToList(player);
            Log.e("Player with a name " + player.getName(), "Has been   created");
    }
```

And code of second activity

```
 submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            if (defaultRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                status=0;
            } else if (driverRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                status=1;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Suka viberi galochku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StartActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("Status",status);
            bundle.putString("Name", name);
            Log.d("Object " + name, "Status: " + status);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help/advice

Comment: In which line does the NPE happen? What variables are used? Can you add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: NPE happens in first activity when I am not checking if Bundle exists as I am setting status from bundle which doesn't exist yet.
player.setStatus(bundle.getInt("Status"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) for this situation.

1) You open second activity from the first using this method, not `startActivity()`
2) Do whatever you want in the second activity
3) Set result bundle
4) Finish activity
5) Open bundle in the first activity

In your case it will look like:

1) Call second activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_SECOND_ACTIVITY); // request code const
```

2-4)

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            if (defaultRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                status=0;
            } else if (driverRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                status=1;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Suka viberi galochku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            final Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("Status", status); // set values
            returnIntent.putExtra("Name", name);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent); // set result code
            finish(); // finish this activity and go back to the previous one
        }
    });
```

5) Override this method in the first activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SECOND_ACTIVITY: // same request code const
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Player player = new Player();
                player.setStatus(data.getIntExtra("Status"));
                player.setName(data.getStringExtra("Name"));
                addPlayerToList(player);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `Intent.putExtra()` instead of putting data into a bundle, and use `Intent.getStringExtra()` to get a String data;

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no code to put your `bundle` into `intent`. actually you never pass the bundle to first activity. you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819427/6340959) to solve your problem.

good luck!