# visibility depends on another activity

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app in which I want to apply button visibility functionality in activity_2 and that visibility should depend on button click from activity_1

Ex. In activity_2 I have :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
android:text="ABC"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

It should visible on button click from activity_1

Activity_1 :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
android:text="ABC"/>
```

Please suggest me, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Pass the visibility you want from Activity A to Activity B in a `Bundle`.

[Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

Comment: Yes..I Think so we can use Bundle but I don't  know how to use.Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On clicking the button in the first activity,send a value to second activity through intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
 intent.putExtra("button","clicked");
 startActivity(intent);
```

And then get this value in the `onCreate` of second activity like this:

```
 String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("button");
```

then check the value with if statement

```
 if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("clicked")){
    //make your button visible here
  }
 else{
   //button not visible
  }
```