# How can i send data of list to another activity after checked the checkbox and click button?

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to send the selected data of list to another activity after button click
[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0):

On button click you check which checkboxs were checked with the method isChecked() and send the information using an intent. To receive the data on the other activity you can use a bundle.

You can check how to send/receive data to another activity using a bundle in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity):