# How to store User Input Text in array and display it in a ListView Android

Tags: listview, arraylist

This is a new Activity where I *read* some user input.

[image]

So when I click the `ADD BUTTON` I want to get the two user input and show them in a ListView which is in a different activity. So I want the user input to be displayed in the following ListView (Title in Heading, Password in sub heading of listView):

[image]

Comment: Somehow unclear question though, do you want to have a single item in a listview having a title and a password only? As listView is a scrollable representation of a collection of data (similar in nature) and as i've analyzed, you can't have a collection with only two input fields unless you save the entries so that they could be used later.

Comment: Yeah i want to have a listview which could display a title and password as title and subtitle. Further more lets say i have four inputs in my activity, and when user clicks add then i want to display the the ttlle only in my listView and when i click the title in the (ListView) it could display all the four inputs in another activity.This is the thing i want . Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we create a class for **clsItem** containing the Item and SubItem. Then, we create an arraylist of **clsItem** in which we can add those items whenever the button is clicked. From there, we can set the adapter for our listview. Below is just a sample:

```
List<clsItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new MyType());

ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, items);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please have the luxury to change. Thanks. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks It helped me a little bit somehow . I will verify this.

Comment: Also to store those inputs permanently, I have to use  SQL Database ??

Comment: yeah. much better.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping I wonder if you will help me more. Further more lets say i have four inputs in my activity, and when user clicks add then i want to display the the ttlle only in my listView and when i click the title in the (ListView) it could display all the four inputs in another activity.This is the thing i want . Could you help me? –

Comment: where do you want to display those four inputs?

Comment: After adding the 4 inputs when i click the listview , i want it to be displayed in a seperate activity..

Comment: Hi @SudeepG . I wasn't able to respond to you these past few days. Can you like state the user story of how things will work in the GUI? Thanks.

Comment: I have developed my program as on the video                                                    https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3065812653&feature=iv&src_vid=SK98ayjhk1E&v=aQAIMY-HzL8

Comment: If you cna view this link then my half problem is solved. In this video, one input is passed and displayed in another activity list view. But i want to pass different inputs(lets assume 4 inputs (TITLE<NAME<PASSSWORD<HINT)  and then i want to display Title only in list view and when clicking the title list in list view i want to open a new page where i can display those three inputs (NAME<PASSWORD<HINT) so if you can help with some ideas??

Comment: can you like pass as a single object containing multiple data / information?

Comment: N i have only passed a single data only But I want to pass a single object having multiple info Help me

Comment: what are the parameters that you specify in your new activity?

Comment: hi @SudeepG have you tried using bundles. i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity) link that might help you regarding passing multiple values to another activity.