# How can I use intent to put data but do not jump to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using intent to transfer data.

When I try the following code,

Intent intent=getIntent() or Intent intent=getIntent(DrawerActivity.this, null)

Exception will occur.

How can I use intent to put data but do not jump to another activity?

Comment: Why do you want to use an `Intent`? From to which place do you want to transfer data?

Comment: Couldn't understand your question, please explain clearly.

Comment: unclear Question....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put data somewhere on the app and not use it instantly, then You can store some values on SharedPreferences, especially if it's not huge amount of data

Answer (score 0):

Intent is a mechanism to pass data from one activity to another.
If you have to store some data in a place and then later send it to another activity,  create a bundle, store data in it and then when you have to go to next activity then create a intent, set the class of the next activity and in putExtras pass the bundle and the data will be sent to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends of situation, you can use [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) or you can create [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and put in it what values you want and when you want to start the activity then pass the Bundle as desctibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity).