# Problem with getting id from bundle in android

Tags: java, android, bundle

i am having problem in getting the id in second activity, i am passing id in bundle like below in first activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(Constants.ID, featured.getId());
                bundle.putString(Constants.TITLE, "Team");
                openAcitivty(getBundle("Questions" , (Serializable) featured.getAll().getQa()) , ProviderQAactivity.class );
```

but when i am getting the id in the second activity, it is showing me zero here

```
 uid = getIntent().getBundleExtra(Constants.DATA).getInt(Constants.ID);
```

please suggests something.

Comment: Simply use `getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.ID)`

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: You aren't sending `bundle` to the `intent`.

Comment: have you put bundle to intent already ?

Comment: where @TruongGiangDam  ?

Comment: @SaadHashmi  Did you put bundle data to intent to start ProviderQAactivity activity use method putExtras(Bundle data) ?

Comment: @SaadHashmi: Maybe you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.ID)
getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.TITLE)
```

may solve your problem.

Also let us know whats inside below function. Are you passing the bundle correctly to next activity via intent.

```
  `openAcitivty(getBundle("Questions" , (Serializable) featured.getAll().getQa()) , ProviderQAactivity.class );`
```

It must contain some code as

```
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: _Constants.TITLE_ is `String` not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
uid = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.ID);
```

when called below line it give bundle object.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```