# Passing data through activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making this music app where I have an activity that i want to display songs in a playlist and another  activity to add songs to the playlist.I want to be able to select songs in the "AddSongsToPlaylist" Activity and display them in the "Playlist activity".
Any ideas how i can do that?[Here are the images representing each of the activities][]

Comment: Use an Intent and putExtra(...) to pass data between Activities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code for sending ArrayAdapter to another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926145/code-for-sending-arrayadapter-to-another-activity)