# how to pass data from activity to adapter?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have 2 Activities. Activity A contains recyclerview, and Activity B is going to pass the Arraylist data to recyclerview in Acrivity A.

my Adapter is like this.

```
public MainAdapter(MainActivity context,ArrayList<MainData> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
```

and MetaData.

```
public MainData(String tv_name, String tv_content) {
    this.tv_name = tv_name;
    this.tv_content = tv_content;
}
```

Activity A (that receives arraylist data):

```
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    list = (ArrayList<MainData>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");

    adapter = new MainAdapter(this,list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AAnd Activity B that pass Arraylist :

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(upload.this, MainActivity.class);

            ArrayList<MainData> list = new ArrayList<MainData>();

            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
            String tv_name = edit.getText().toString();

            EditText edit_main = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_main);
            String tv_content = edit_main.getText().toString();

            list.add(new MainData(tv_name,tv_content));

            intent.putExtra("key", list);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And it throws Runtime Exception.

Answer (score 0):

The context you provided is not complete, please review the Android guide. If you need to transfer data between activities, please check this article
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Intent extras to pass the the array list from ActivityB to `ActivityA` and in the `ActivityA` you have to pass the list to the adapter so it will set the data on the recyclerView.

You shouldn't directly pass the data from `ActivityB` to the adapter of `AdapterA`

This might be helpful: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent